# Grid system using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have next html:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Date:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="date" id="txtDate" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Parent or Guardian Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="parent_name" id="txtParentName" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="txtEmail" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="address" id="txtAddress" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It's render some form for contact (part of form). And result looks like [image]

I want to skip somehow space that still exists in row ( i use `col-md-3` for label and `col-md-4` for input. As result just 7 of 12.) I try with `offset` and `push` but this doesn't help, as `offset` display label in center of page and `push` displays label out of viewport.

Comment: You should consider using col-sm as well for your designs as on smaller mac screens it can get jumbled. Are you wanting two seperate columns with space in middle or just centered all in middle?

Comment: @arinh, yes, i don't forget about it. It's just to show you what i have. Thanks for note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class `clearfix` on your `form-groups` to keep inside just the elements of each one:

> ```
> <div class="form-group clearfix">
> ```

#### [BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/oFaTO81Xmx)

Comment: Argh... Yeah, this is what i Want. Thanks a lot